# How this prime test function works?

Tags: javascript, regex, primes

I saw this prime test code at another programming commnunity.

```
isPrime=n=>!/^.$|^(..+)\1+$/.test(Array(n+1));
```

I can understand RegExp thing, But I couldn't understand how this is work.

Why empty array is inside a RegExp test? and why it works???
I searched it but i couldn't find any informations... :(

Comment: Where did you get that snippet from?

Comment: @Sam The question could be presented better, but it's not all that unclear IMO, it's a very interesting algorithm

Comment: @CertainPerformance feel free to answer now

Comment: `Array(n+1)` in this context is the same as `','.repeat(n)` ... so, the test is run on n `,` characters ... interesting ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start with, the regex is being tested against `Array(n+1))`. When `.test` is passed a non-string, it gets cast to a string.

`String(Array(5))` results in `,,,,` (4 commas). `String(Array(3))` results in `,,` (2 commas), and so on. (All elements of the array are joined by `,`, resulting in `length - 1` commas).

So, `isPrime(n)` results in a regex being tested against a string composed of `n` commas.

Now, for the interesting bit: the regex. The first part is `^.$`, a trivial case of when the input is 1. This doesn't really matter, so feel free to ignore it.

The important part is `^(..+)\1+$`:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(` - Start of group

  - `..+` - Match 2 or more characters
- `)` - End of group
- `\1+` - Repeat the group that was previously matched 1 or more times
- `$` - End of string

In plain language, the initial capture group will match 2 or more characters, and then that capture group will be repeated 2 or more times total, and the full match will span the entire length of the string.

So, for example, the composite number 4 can be matched by `,,` being matched in the first capture group, and by that group being backreferenced (matched again) once more.

The composite number 9 can be matched by `,,,` being matched in the first capture group, and by that group being backreferenced twice more.

The prime number 5 cannot be matched, because there are no sub-segments of the string such that repeating the sub-segment N times (where N is 2 or more) will result in 5.

So, the whole regex `/^.$|^(..+)\1+$/` will be fulfilled against a string if the string is composite. Invert that test, and you get a  check of if the number of repeated commas is prime.